# creating a variable with a value of a drop down selection input (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've had a hard time finding a similar question for this, and its probably simple but just slipping my mind.

I've got a drop down menu, you make your selection and submit it, it jumps to 2ndpage.html?location=locationName

I'm trying to create a variable with a value of the "locationName" to use in a link that would use that value as a string like "www.locationName.com",

i've tried using something like 
var locationName = getElementById("location").value;
and other similar ways but the variable seems to keep coming up undefined. And this seems to be the only thing stopping me from finishing my project, lol.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share some of your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would find the value and text by accessing **this.selectedIndex** of the selection list. Use **http://** for absolute link to a page.

```
<select id="locations">
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Location 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.loogle.com" selected="selected">Location 2</option>
  <option value="http://www.foogle.com">Location 3</option>
</select>

var e = document.getElementById("locations");
e.addEventListener('change', function (){
    var locationValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;//www.loogle.com
    var locationText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;//Location 2
    window.location = locationValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>Location: </p>
    <select id="location">
        <option value="location1">location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">location 2</option>
        <option value="location3">location 3</option>
    </select>
<script>
var locationName = document.getElementById("location").value;
</script>
```

Or try this:

```
<p>Location: </p>
    <select name="location">
        <option value="location1">location 1</option>
        <option value="location2">location 2</option>
        <option value="location3">location 3</option>
    </select>
<script>
var locationName = document.getElementsByName("location")[0].value;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i'm realizing that code WOULD work but my issue is that when i select an item from the drop down and submit it, it goes to a new HTML page, effectively resetting the variable to undefined. I believe this is the case anyway.

Comment: Can you post the script?